# Azure Active Directory Redirect URI not working properly in React Application deployed in IIS

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have a React application that uses Azure Active Directory and msal.js to authenticate.

I can run it in debug (after the user logs in, he is redirected to the URI I have defined in the Azure Portal as http://localhost:3000/authCallback and this does some work to set cookies and then redirects to a valid URL e.g /databases, that opens a real page of the application), but when I deploy the SPA in IIS (local server for testing), the callback redirect from azure does not work.

I can see that Azure returns the correct URI since the browser contains something like "http://localhost:3000/authCallback#id_token=a_valid_token...", but I get the error below that I couldn't understand why is happening.

[image: IIS error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out after I've found this [useful post on Medium](https://medium.com/@mateioprea/setting-up-a-react-app-with-react-router-in-iis-71cb86aee376)

Basically, I was missing the web.config in the root of the React Application and I needed to install the URL Rewrite in the server, then restarted the IIS.